# How to get the checkboxes value in checked order in php

Tags: php, checkbox

In the registration part there will be some images and it will shuffle automatically in each refresh. user should select one or more images (tick the corresponding checkboxes) and it will stored in database instead of password.It will work correctly and problem is in login page.I want the values of checkboxes in checked order. that means if I checked second checkbox and then first box,then value will get the same order.

here is the code

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if(isset($_POST['s'])){
$username=$_POST['username'];
if(isset($_POST['chk1']))
{
 $t1=implode(',', $_POST['chk1']);
}
echo $t1;
$query=mysql_query("select *from register where username='$username' and password='$t1'");
$res=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($res>0)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION['usr']=$username;
header("location:userhome.php");
}
else
{
 echo mysql_error();
 }
 }
 ?>

<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<table width="200" border="0">
<th colspan="2" scope="row"><a href="register.php">
<font color="#FF0000">New Registration</font>      </a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">Username</th>
<td><label for="username"></label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th colspan="2" scope="row"><u>Choose Password</u></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th scope="row">&nbsp;</th>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div align="center">
<?php
$images = array(
'<input name="chk1[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<img src="images/images (4).jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />',
'<input name="chk1[]" type="checkbox" value="2"  />
<img src="images/images (6).jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />',
'<input name="chk1[]" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<img src="images/images (5).jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />', 
'<input name="chk1[]" type="checkbox" value="4" />
 <img src="images/drt.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />',
'<input name="chk1[]"   type="checkbox" value="5" />
 <img src="images/rf.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />',
'<input name="chk1[]" type="checkbox" value="6" />
<img src="images/yu.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />', 
'<input name="chk1[]" type="checkbox" value="7" />
 <img src="images/ed.jpg" alt="" width="234" height="212" />'
  );
shuffle($images); // Randomize images array;
echo $images[0];
echo $images[1];
echo $images[2];
echo $images[3];
echo $images[4];
echo $images[5];
echo $images[6];
?>
```

Comment: is anybody have the solution.please help me

Comment: please give me a solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible with PHP, you need to implement it in JavaScript.
Create internal aray with JS to store checkbox checking order and send
it to PHP target file.

Here I written a "easy" but not elegant solution as example:

```
<form name="myform">

    <input id="chk1" name="chk1" type="checkbox" onclick="validate1()" /> test 1

    <input id="chk2" name="chk2" type="checkbox" onclick="validate2()" /> test 2

    <input id="chk3" name="chk3" type="checkbox" onclick="validate3()" /> test 3

    <input type="hidden" name="order"/>

    <input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="fin()">
</form>

    <script>
    var arrChecks = [];
    function validate1(){
        if (document.getElementById('chk1').checked) arrChecks.push( 1 );
    }

    function validate2(){
        if (document.getElementById('chk2').checked) arrChecks.push( 2 );
    }

    function validate3(){
        if (document.getElementById('chk3').checked) arrChecks.push( 3 );
    }

    function fin(){

        alert(arrChecks); // Show order, only for debug

       document.myform.order.value = arrChecks.toString(); // Array of checked options order
       document.myform.submit();                           // Send to php file
    }
    </script>
```

To perform it more elegant and optimized, a dynamic iteration would be needed.  But this code works.

regards

Comment: whether I use <input type="submit">

Comment: And how to i get the same value in php??

Comment: It's easy to change submit default button, use instead the javascript function triggered by a onclick event.  About your second question (to get the same value in php) I can't understand you, please explain

Comment: When I clicked on submit button,I get a javascript alert of values of checkboxes in checked order (eg:2,6,4). alert(arrChecks); .Then I want to get the same alert value in '$tl'.so only i can perform login.

Comment: delete alert, I written it only for debug.  Take a look here:       

document.myform.order.value = arrChecks.toString();
document.myform.submit();     

this will send the order field (hidden) with information

Comment: Thanku for the great help