# PHP: How do I find the order in which the check boxes were selected?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a PHP code like the one below to see which all players were selected, using a checkbox and a table:

```
<?php
  $players = $crud->readPlayers();
  if (mysql_num_rows($players) > 0) 
   {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($players))
     {
      ?>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="player[]" value="<?php echo $row['player_code'] ?>"></td><td> <?php echo $row['player_name'] ?></td> 
      </tr>
     <?php
    }
   }
   else{
    ?><tr><td colspan="2"><center>No to select. Please add before creating a team!</center></td></tr>
  <?php
  } 
?>
```

This form is handled by another page as:

```
if(isset($_POST['player'])){
            $i=1;
            foreach($_POST['player'] as $player_code){

              $crud->addTeam($team_id, $player_code,$i++);    
    }
```

where the third parameter passed to `addTeam()`is supposed to be the order of players, or the number assigned to the player. Although I get all selected players in the team, I can view the team and players from terminal, I am unable to number them correctly as the order of selection of check boxes, i.e., if checkbox with player name 'a' printed next to it is selected after the one with name 'b', it should get a number 2, and not 1.
Then, I have to list the whole team in increasing order of player number. `player_code` is used to store player details in another table, and can vary accordingly, i.e., player named 'a' need not have `player_code` set as 1.

How to I get the order of selection of these check boxes and assign number to players accordingly, without using anything except HTML and PHP ?

Comment: when you say html you mean javascript, too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the checkboxes value in checked order in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939718/how-to-get-the-checkboxes-value-in-checked-order-in-php)

Comment: _“How to I get the order of selection of these check boxes and assign number to players accordingly, without using anything except HTML and PHP ?”_ – with that limitation: Not at all, of course.

Comment: You will need some logic on the client to record those details for you. However, why not just have a box that the user can fill in that specifies the order they want? That way no-one gets confused and the user can change it whenever they wish?  Clicking boxes in a certain order sounds like an opportunity  for confusion between user and you? Unless you add a box to show the order clicked? At which point we are back at the start of this comment?

Comment: and dont use the mysql driver.. its deprecated (removed in php7) and the world will explode (as well as youre site)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding JavaScript to the checkboxes checked/click event.
So everytime users click one chk, you could store the player name in another field (maybe hidden?).
In that way you will be generating a list of player names in the exact order they were clicked, in that hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will also submit form data in the order in which it appears *in the form*. There is no information about what order controls were selected in.

## The Grid

A plain HTML approach would be to have a *grid* of radio buttons. e.g. each row represents a player and each column a position.

You would need to write PHP that would validate the submitted data to make sure that any given player wasn't selected multiple times.

## Multiple pages

Alternatively, you could require that one player be selected (and submitted to the server) at a time.

Each time the form is submitted, you return a new form with the selected players listed in hidden inputs and omitted from the choices given to the user.

This could be rather slow though.

## JavaScript

Violating your HTML+PHP only constraint, you could use JavaScript.

Listen for click events on the checkboxes and store the values in a hidden input (e.g. as a comma separated list).